# SQL Server - whole DB in memory?

Tags: sql-server, scalability

In the context of high scalability, how is it possible to keep all of your SQL Server DB in memory in order to speed up operations? I have read on websites such as www.highscalability.com that many large websites purposefully store the entire DB in memory in order to speed up operations.

Do you simply read every table into objects and then store them in a cache or some sort?

Or is there some magical switch in SQL Server which tells it to store itself in RAM?

Comment: SQL Server automatically caches frequently accessed pages behind the scenes.

Comment: So...if I add more RAM to my server, does that mean that SQL Server will fill up all available RAM automatically?

Comment: My understanding is if you configure your buffer pool cache memory to be more than the size of the databases accessed through sql server, then you'll essentially end up with everything cached in memory. Here's some info on that with further links to more detail http://www.johnsansom.com/the-sql-server-buffer-pool-and-buffer-cache-hit-ratio/

Comment: SQL Server will fill up memory based on the memory configuration parameters.  The documentation is here (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx).  If there is enough memory, then tables will quickly be cached in the page cache, speeding up queries.